# How to use fillna together with groupby for time series?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataset:

```
Date,Day,A,B,C  
2015/03/23,Mo,60085,105744,18623  
2015/03/24,Tu,41472,70327,14775  
2015/03/25,We,46644,81693,17168  
2015/03/26,Th,43640,74615,15577  
2015/03/27,Fr,37503,67754,13278  
2015/03/28,Sa,,,  
2015/03/29,Su,,,  
2015/03/30,Mo,61904,108128,19600  
2015/03/31,Tu,48376,80326,17512  
2015/04/01,We,48529,,17815  
2015/04/02,Th,45491,74744,15524  
2015/04/03,Fr,,,  
2015/04/04,Sa,,,  
2015/04/05,Su,,,  
2015/04/06,Mo,,,  
2015/04/07,Tu,65738,120412,19082  
2015/04/08,We,44792,81468,16796  
2015/04/09,Th,40930,70810,13664  
2015/04/10,Fr,39367,60249,11882
```

I would like to fill all NA in Mon-Fr with either:

1. The previous weeks value
2. The average of previous and next

So on 2015/04/01 I would like to have:

1. 81693
2. (81693+81468)/2=81580.5

I thought that I would be able to use groupby and fillna with ffill but I am not sure if that is possible or if it is the best way.

Comment: I recommend that you add more data to this question and also, list what your expected results from that data would look like.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to as good Pandas questions.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that none of the dates are missing.

```
df['date'] = df['date].map(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x,"%d/%m/%Y"))
df.sort_values(by=['date'],inplace=True)
cols = ['v1','v2','v3','v4']
cols_last_week = [i+'_last_week' for i in cols]
df[cols_last_week] = df[cols].shiftby(7)
```

Let's say v1 has nulls

```
df.loc[df['v1'].isnull(),'v1'] = df.loc[df['v1'].isnull(),'v1_last_week']
```